# jspdf-autotable when addPage not reset cursorY

Tags: angular5, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm using didDrawCell hook to add new page when it draws five rows table, but it seems that after new page, startY is not reseting to 0, but continue the previouse. did I do wrong in my code.

Im using Angular 5 and jspdf-autotable

This is my code:

```
    autoTable(doc, {
               startY: 50,
                margin: margenTabla,
                theme: "plain",
                columns: tablaJson.dataColumnas,
                body: tablaJson.dataValores,
                styles: {
                    fontSize: 8,
                },
                didDrawCell: function (data) {
                    if ((data.row.index > 0 && data.row.index % 5 == 0) && (data.column.index == data.table.columns.length-1)) {
                        doc.addPage();    
                    }                      
                },                    
            });
```